# Boots only to flashing cursor

Tags: boot, system-installation

On a single boot (Linux only) older Acer Veriton desktop system, no matter which flavor of Linux I've installed, all boot only to the flashing cursor once successfully installed. I tried Ubuntu Studio, Lubuntu and the Ubuntu-based Linuxfx but all do the same thing so it must be some hardware issue/setting conflicting in some way with Linux. Since this PC had Ubuntu Studio on it and up and running last week before I decided to do a fresh install, that makes no sense.

To remove the possibility of it trying to access different devices, I removed everything external and set the BIOS to see only the internal hard drive in the boot device area. Right now I am booted to the Live version of Ubuntu Studio 22.10 which has no problem running live until I install it, then the blinking cursor again.

Thinking it might be graphic card related, most issues seem to point to Nvidia or AMD but this system has Mesa Intel G45/G43. However, even if there were some conflict, I can't boot to change it.

UEFI, if I'm remembering the correct acronym, is another possibility but I see no option for it in the system BIOS unless it might be there under a different name. Otherwise I would try to set or unset it, depending on the current state.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try alt right arrow a few times?

Comment: Yes I did but I am now 700 miles away from the PC and won’t be back to try again for a couple months. I did bring the hard drive back with me, though, to run some diagnostics on it.